# UIautomator Test Case Android

Tags: android, android-uiautomator, junit3

I'm  working with UiAutomator, but I unable to extend my class with UIAutomatorTestCase,
Also I had added the jar files ie UIAutomator jar files and JUnit3 lib.
I'm getting error in this class
And also i want to knw how to build the testcases for that application plus How can I run the test cases from my application
programmatically? if no then how i can run these test cases.

```
  package com.example.test;

import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class UiAutomatorTestCase extends TestCase {

    private static final String DISABLE_IME = "disable_ime";
    private static final String DUMMY_IME_PACKAGE = "com.android.testing.dummyime";
    private UiDevice mUiDevice;
    private Bundle mParams;
    private IAutomationSupport mAutomationSupport;
    private boolean mShouldDisableIme = false;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        mShouldDisableIme = "true".equals(mParams.getString(DISABLE_IME));
        if (mShouldDisableIme) {
            setDummyIme();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        if (mShouldDisableIme) {
            restoreActiveIme();
        }
        super.tearDown();
    }

    /**
     * Get current instance of {@link UiDevice}. Works similar to calling the static {@link UiDevice#getInstance()} from anywhere in the test classes.
     */
    public UiDevice getUiDevice() {
        return mUiDevice;
    }

    /**
     * Get command line parameters. On the command line when passing <code>-e key value</code> pairs, the {@link Bundle} will have the key value pairs conveniently available to the
     * tests.
     */
    public Bundle getParams() {
        return mParams;
    }

    /**
     * Provides support for running tests to report interim status
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public IAutomationSupport getAutomationSupport() {
        return mAutomationSupport;
    }

    /**
     * package private
     * 
     * @param uiDevice
     */
    void setUiDevice(UiDevice uiDevice) {
        mUiDevice = uiDevice;
    }

    /**
     * package private
     * 
     * @param params
     */
    void setParams(Bundle params) {
        mParams = params;
    }

    void setAutomationSupport(IAutomationSupport automationSupport) {
        mAutomationSupport = automationSupport;
    }

    /**
     * Calls {@link SystemClock#sleep(long)} to sleep
     * 
     * @param ms
     *            is in milliseconds.
     */
    public void sleep(long ms) {
        SystemClock.sleep(ms);
    }

    protected void setDummyIme() throws RemoteException {
        IInputMethodManager im = IInputMethodManager.Stub.asInterface(ServiceManager.getService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE));
        List<InputMethodInfo> infos = im.getInputMethodList();
        String id = null;
        for (InputMethodInfo info : infos) {
            if (DUMMY_IME_PACKAGE.equals(info.getComponent().getPackageName())) {
                id = info.getId();
            }
        }
        if (id == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Required testing fixture missing: IME package (%s)", DUMMY_IME_PACKAGE));
        }
        im.setInputMethod(null, id);
    }

    protected void restoreActiveIme() throws RemoteException {
        // TODO: figure out a way to restore active IME
        // Currently retrieving active IME requires querying secure settings provider, which is hard
        // to do without a Context; so the caveat here is that to make the post test device usable,
        // the active IME needs to be manually switched.
    }
}
```

Following class is to test the calculator.
But I dont knw how to use it..
Here's the [link](http://university.utest.com/android-ui-testing-uiautomatorviewer-and-uiautomator/)

```
package com.example.test;

import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiScrollable;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiSelector;
import com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase;

public class DemoCalTest extends UiAutomatorTestCase {
    public void testingCalculator() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {

        // First we testing the press of the HOME button.

        getUiDevice().pressHome();

        // using the uiautomatorviewer tool we found that the button for the "applications" has

        //the value “Apps” (screen9)

        // so we use this property to create a UiSelector to find the button. 

        UiObject Applications = new UiObject(new UiSelector().description("Apps"));

        // testing the click to bring up the All Apps screen.

        Applications.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();

        // In the All Apps screen, the "Calculator" application is located in 

        // the Apps tab. So, we create a UiSelector to find a tab with the text 

        // label “Apps”.

        UiObject apps = new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Apps"));

        // and then testing the click to this tab in order to enter the Apps tab.

        apps.click();

        // All the applications are in a scrollable list 

        // so first we need to get a reference to that list

        UiScrollable ListOfapplications = new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true));

        // and then trying to find the application    

        // with the name Calculator

        UiObject Calculator = ListOfapplications.getChildByText(new UiSelector().className(android.widget.TextView.class.getName()), "Calculator");

        Calculator.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();

        // now the Calculator app is open

        // so we can test the press of button "7" using the ID "com.android.calculator2:id/digit7"

        //we found by using uiautomatorviewer

        UiObject seven = new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.android.calculator2:id/digit7"));

        seven.click();

        // now we test the press of button "+"

        UiObject plus = new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.android.calculator2:id/plus"));

        plus.click();

        // and then the press of button "1"

        UiObject one = new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.android.calculator2:id/digit1"));

        one.click();

        // we test the press of button "="

        UiObject result = new UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId("com.android.calculator2:id/equal"));

        result.click();

        //and finally we test the press of "Back" button

        getUiDevice().pressBack();

    }
}
```

I googled alot but could find any explanation about it.
 Can any one help me out.
I am new to it
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you should be extending your class:

```
public class <yourClassName> extends UiAutomatorTestCase {
```

We also need to import `uiautomator.jar` which usually resides in `~/sdk/platforms/android-xx/`

You can kick start from [Link1](http://looksok.wordpress.com/2014/02/08/uiautomator-in-eclipse) and [Link2](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html)

Comment: im unable to extend class with UiAutomatorTestCase

Comment: should i need to add any lib except UIAutomator jar files and JUnit3 lib ??

Comment: Anvesh: hi,
i checked ~/sdk/platforms/android-xx/ (in Windows) but didnt find uiautomatorviewer jar..

Comment: Is your SDK and ADT latest? If not, please download it from here: http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r23.0.2-windows.exe

Comment: Do u have a sample code for it?
Act i m new to it.
didnt find any gud tutorial on net

Comment: You can Check http://looksok.wordpress.com/2014/02/08/uiautomator-in-eclipse/ and http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html

Comment: ok 
thanks dear
do we need to add any permission to manifest?

Comment: Anvesh Yalamarthy: okz, but how to check it.

Comment: You need to compile your code to jar file using ant and push it to /data/local/tmp of your emulator or phone and run a shell commmand see if your test is running.. please check urls shared by me earlier..

Comment: Anvesh Yalamarthy: Hi
Still not getting how to use it :(

Comment: Hey, I am not getting to use it, i dont knw how to run the unit test cases

Comment: did you check "Building and Deploying Your uiautomator Tests" section in http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html?

Comment: hey , can try out my blog post here about uiautomator. I have mentioned all the steps there - http://smritituteja.in/android-automation-uiautomator/

Comment: Thanks Smriti for sharing.. It's indeed a good tutorial.. Keep up the good work :)

Comment: @Smriti Ive checked out your tutorial. Is there any way to run the file without using the terminal? I tried running it thru Eclipse as an Android JUnit Test, and it gave a NullPointerException

Comment: Also, if possible please check out my quesiton: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392443/android-runtime-error-while-uitesting //@Smriti

Answer (score 0):

Since Gradle was introduced as a new build tool, you don't have to include any jars. Just add

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
```

as a dependency to the `build.gradle` file.

For example:

```
dependencies {
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'

}
```