# Android: Runtime error while UiTesting

Tags: android, unit-testing, ui-automation, android-testing, android-uiautomator

I am trying to run a Ui test, and everytime I run the applicatoin it gives the following error in the console and closes the app that is running. I have the uiautomator.jar, android.jar & JUnit4 libraries imported. Im using Eclipse. What am I missing here?

> [2016-04-04 04:44:00 - UiTests] Test run failed: Instrumentation run
>   failed due to 'java.lang.RuntimeException'

**TestClass**

```
package android.support.v7.appcompat.test;

import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObject;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiObjectNotFoundException;
import com.android.uiautomator.core.UiSelector;
import com.android.uiautomator.testrunner.UiAutomatorTestCase;

public class DMTest extends UiAutomatorTestCase
{
    public void testDemo() throws UiObjectNotFoundException
    {
        // setText
        new UiObject(new UiSelector().description("edittext_brute")).setText("bazinga");

        // clickButton
        //new UiObject(new UiSelector().description("button_done")).click();

        UiObject btDone = new UiObject(new UiSelector().description("button_done"));
        btDone.click();
    }

}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="android.support.v7.appcompat.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

    <instrumentation
    android:name="android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
    android:targetPackage="com.example.sony.reel" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Edit 1: It gives the same exception even if there is no code within the testDemo() constructor

Edit 2: Logcat

> Could not find test class...

```
04-04 07:25:48.539: E/AndroidRuntime(12026): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 07:25:48.539: E/AndroidRuntime(12026): Process: com.example.sony.reel, PID: 12026
04-04 07:25:48.539: E/AndroidRuntime(12026): java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception thrown in onCreate() of ComponentInfo{android.support.v7.appcompat.test/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find test class. Class: android.support.v7.appcompat.test.DMTest
04-04 07:25:48.539: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4599)
04-04 07:25:48.539: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:148)
04-04 07:25:48.539: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1353)
04-04 07:25:48.539: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-04 07:25:48.539: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-04 07:25:48.539: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
04-04 07:25:48.539: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-04 07:25:48.539: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-04 07:25:48.539: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
04-04 07:25:48.539: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
04-04 07:25:48.539: E/AndroidRuntime(12026): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find test class. Class: android.support.v7.appcompat.test.DMTest
04-04 07:25:48.539: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runFailed(AndroidTestRunner.java:255)
04-04 07:25:48.539: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.loadTestClass(AndroidTestRunner.java:89)
04-04 07:25:48.539: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.setTestClassName(AndroidTestRunner.java:50)
04-04 07:25:48.539: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.addTestClassByName(TestSuiteBuilder.java:78)
04-04 07:25:48.539: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.parseTestClass(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:444)
04-04 07:25:48.539: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.parseTestClasses(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:425)
04-04 07:25:48.539: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:371)
04-04 07:25:48.539: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4596)
04-04 07:25:48.539: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    ... 9 more
```

Comment: can you post the full error ?

Comment: That's the only error, there are 4 other lines in the console, its like: detecting device..installing apk..launching.. and then this

Comment: Btw, this is running from an Android Test Project in eclipse

Comment: what is your run configuration ? Also check logcat for more errors then

Comment: I've updated it with the logcat. It says could not find test class? Its running as an Android JUnit Test . Is that what you meant by run config?

Comment: Also, im using JUnit4 ; could that be an issue? As most examples I see use JUnit3

Comment: i wonder how you compile this- by making jar or making apk ?

Comment: Im running is straight. Ctr+F11 . So APK I guess

Answer (score 0):

[Android](http://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html) recommends to use studio for uiautomator test projects and gradle for building.

In your case try adding `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)` annotation at the beginning of your test class definition.

Your code sample will definitely work if you move this to studio. Or compile with `ant` and run with compiled jar file.